# Docker installation failed on Ubuntu 16.04 (unknown error)

Tags: 16.04, server, docker

I’m trying to install BigBlueButton and it workes so far (sudo bbb-conf --status marks all parts as active).
The docker installation using the repository fails, though (`sudo apt-get install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd .io`).

```
Setting up docker-ce (5:20.10.3~3-0~ubuntu-xenial) … Job for
docker.service failed because the control process exited with error
code. See “systemctl status docker.service” and “journalctl -xe” for
details. invoke-rc.d: initscript docker, action “start” failed.
    ● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
    Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
    Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2021-02-19 14:48:45 CET; 4ms ago
    Docs: *************
    Process: 7021 ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
    Main PID: 7021 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Feb 19 14:48:45 ubuntuserver systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker
Application …
    Feb 19 14:48:45 ubuntuserver systemd[1]: docker.service: Unit entered failed…
    Feb 19 14:48:45 ubuntuserver systemd[1]: docker.service: Failed with result …
    Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
    dpkg: error processing package docker-ce (–configure):
    subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
    dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of docker-ce-rootless-extras:
    docker-ce-rootless-extras depends on docker-ce; however:
    Package docker-ce is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package docker-ce-rootless-extras (–configure):
    dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
    No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
    Processing triggers for systemd (229-4ubuntu21.29) …
    Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-19.1) …
    Errors were encountered while processing:
    docker-ce
    docker-ce-rootless-extras
    E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

`systemctl status docker.service` says:

```
docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
    Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: e
    Active: failed (Result: start-limit-hit) since Fri 2021-02-19 14:48:54 CET; 8
    Docs: *************
    Process: 7267 ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd
    Main PID: 7267 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
```

`journalctl -xe` says:

```
Feb 19 14:56:48 ubuntuserver systemd[1]: Stopped target BigBlueButton
recording

– Subject: Unit bbb-record-core.target has finished shutting down
    – Defined-By: systemd
    – Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
    – Unit bbb-record-core.target has finished shutting down.
    Feb 19 14:57:06 ubuntuserver systemd_start.sh[1606]: info: Checking for inactive
    Feb 19 14:57:06 ubuntuserver systemd_start.sh[1606]: info: No inactive users
    Feb 19 14:57:29 ubuntuserver systemd[1]: Reached target BigBlueButton recording
    – Subject: Unit bbb-record-core.target has finished start-up
    – Defined-By: systemd
    – Support: *************
    – Unit bbb-record-core.target has finished starting up.
    – The start-up result is done.
    Feb 19 14:57:29 ubuntuserver systemd[1]: bbb-record-core.target: Unit not needed
    Feb 19 14:57:29 ubuntuserver systemd[1]: Stopped target BigBlueButton recording
    – Subject: Unit bbb-record-core.target has finished shutting down
    – Defined-By: systemd
    – Support: *************

Unit bbb-record-core.target has finished shutting down.
```

I tried for days now. Uninstalled and deleted everything as seen on docker page (“uninstalling docker”). Some guys had similar problems but the solutions I found didn’t work for me.

Thanks in advance!
greetings

/edit: I’m using a totally fresh install of Ubuntu Server 16.04. (necessary for BigBlueButton). I installed a GUI (xfce4).

/edit2: "Sometimes we get asked “Why are you only supporting Ubuntu 16.04 64-bit)?”. The answer is based on choosing quality over quantity. Long ago we concluded that its better for the project to have solid, well-tested, well-documented installation for a specific version of Linux that works really, really well than to try and support may variants of Linux and have none of them work well."
This is what BBB installation says.

Comment: You may want to use 18.04 or 20.04 before you try docker again as 16.04 is EOL in April of this year and there will be no more support for it after that.

Comment: Are you sure Ubuntu 16.04 is not a "minimum" requirement - did you try on Ubuntu 20.04?

Comment: EOL means the reporistories might not longer be present, any dependencies not present in the actually downloaded package might be impossible to find.

Comment: While [the minimum server requirements](https://docs.bigbluebutton.org/2.2/install.html#minimum-server-requirements) do state that Ubuntu 16.04 is the lowest supported version *for a bare metal installation*, there is no reason to not use 20.04. If you need to use a GUI and prefer XFCE, then installing Xubuntu 20.04 seems the most logical solution. Since you are using Docker containers, it makes no sense to limit yourself to a five year old OS that is due to exit support in a month's time. Go with 20.04 for maximum compatibility 

Comment: @David Only Ubuntu 16.04 is supported by BBB 2.2, they will support 18.04 in next version

Comment: @Artur Only Ubuntu 16.04 is supported by BBB 2.2, they will support 18.04 in next version

Answer (score 0):

Okay guys, I give up. It only supports 16.04 and I can't find the error on myself :´(
Thanks for your answers anyway :)

Comment: Try the 2.3-dev version on Ubuntu 18.04. Don't use Docker for that, go with the native packages.